# How to make a window active in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows

So I'm working on a program that types into an open application that has no api. So I need to select that window so my program will type into it. I'm using this code and it can't find the proccess.

```
Dim windowHandle As IntPtr = FindWindow("LolClient", "League of Legends (TM) Client")
Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As IntPtr
SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle)

    SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}")
    SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}")
    SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}")
    SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}")
    SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}")
    SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}")
    SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}")
    SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}")
    SendKeys.SendWait(ComboBox1.Text)
    SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}")
```

Comment: You should try looking into the Process Class, in many cases it's much easier to work with.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Integer) As Integer
Public Declare Auto Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Integer
Public Declare Function IsIconic Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Integer) As Boolean
Public Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal nCmdShow As Integer) As Integer

Public Const SW_RESTORE As Integer = 9
Public Const SW_SHOW As Integer = 5


Sub FocusWindow(ByVal strWindowCaption As String, ByVal strClassName As String)
    Dim hWnd As Integer
    hWnd = FindWindow(strClassName, strWindowCaption)

    If hWnd > 0 Then
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd)

        If IsIconic(hWnd) Then  'Restore if minimized
            ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE)
        Else
            ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

To show the "Calculator" you can call `FocusWindow("Calculator", Nothing)` or `FocusWindow(Nothing, "CalcFrame")`

Comment: Thank you! This was the missing link for my project.

Comment: How would you select the window by process name rather than by window title?